# Why does the "all settings" button in unity-control-center have no effect?

Tags: settings, button

I have installed a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop system.  I haven't configured anything yet.  Thus, the very first action was to start the unity-control-center by clicking on the gears icon.  Then, I clicked on the "all settings" button but it has no effect.  Instead, I expected more settings options to appear.

When I start the program on the command line, it does not print any error messages.

Comment: The "All Settings" button is actually the link for `unity-control-center`, so you are actually on the "All Settings" menu. You should upload screenshoots to explain better.

Comment: I start "unity-control-center" from the command line.  Then, a window opens.  In this window is a button "All settings", which has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the System Settings (`unity-control-center` from command line) you get all the settings:

[image: screenshoot1]

Then, if you enter some setting, like *Appearance*, it will look like this now:

[image: screenshoot2]

Now, if you click on the *All Settings* button, it will work going to the main menu.

Comment: You might add that it's similar to breadcrumbs at the top of a web page to show where you are in a path.

Comment: Exactly, the last button is to show where are you in that moment, that is why it doesn't run any event.

Comment: I might add why I was confused: I come from Lubuntu and miss some settings possibilities (which are somewhere else in Ubuntu probably).  I expected "All settings" to be some sort of expert mode, revealing, well, all settings.